# knockout set css conditionally

Tags: css, knockout.js

Sorry for maybe uncorrect question, but I feel really confused. I need to set the css class of an item in a foreach loop based on the value of an item's property.

```
self.CssBind = ko.computed(function (task) {
    var CssBind = '';
    if (getComplexity(task) === 'Easy') {
     CssBind = "green";
 } else if (getComplexity(task) === 'Intermediate') {
     CssBind = 'yellow';}
 else if (getComplexity(task) === 'Difficult') {
     CssBind = 'red';
 }
 return CssBind;
});
```

I tried to get complexity in such way but have undefined.... (in controller there is method that accepts task and returns complexity)

```
self.complexity = ko.observable();
function getComplexity (task) {
    ajaxHelper(taskItem, 'GET').done(function (data) { self.complexity(data); });
};
```

In html

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="foreach:{data:tasks, as: 'task'}">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-bind="text: Name, attr: { href : '#collapse' + task.Id}, css: {color: CssBind}">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="attr: { id : 'collapse' + task.Id}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What to change to make it work?

Comment: how to pass argument to CSSBIND? it is empty in function?

Answer (score 0):

Your `computed` is probably defined on the root view-model and when you're calling it you're already in a `foreach: tasks` scope. You need to use the `$root` keyword to point to `CssBind`.

Also, no need for a `computed`, regular function will do easier (especially with argument passing):

```
self.CssBind = function (task) {
    var CssBind = '';
    if (ko.unwrap(task.getComplexity) === 'Easy') {
     CssBind = "green";
 } else if (self.getComplexity() === 'Intermediate') {
     CssBind = 'yellow';}
 else if (self.getComplexity() === 'Difficult') {
     CssBind = 'red';
 }

 return CssBind;
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse"
   data-parent="#accordion"
   data-bind="text: Name, attr: { href : '#collapse' + task.Id}, style: {color: $root.CssBind.bind(null, task)}">
```

Please notice that I change the binding handler from `css` to `style` (the former is used to apply CSS classes while the latter applies explicit CSS rules).

Comment: if i make it without computed - it just is not called and show accordeon without color css.

Comment: It *should* be called, why not? Also, see my update (`style` instead of `css` binding-handler).

Comment: I found mistake - wrote task instead self - already fix and now I've checked through debugger the passing argument to cssBind function task is undefined.how to pass it properly?

Comment: Are you calling it with `bind` and `$data`, exactly as shown in my answer?

Comment: if i call it as you wrote it unables to bind function

Comment: can i contact with you somehow personally?

Comment: Do you need the current `task` in the `CssBind` function at all?

Comment: I hava set of tasks and for every i need its own color depend upon complexity value

Comment: I just bothered to check the `getComplexity` function. It's clear that it cannot work this way since the complexity is set in an asynchronous way after an Ajax request.

Comment: Well, even if it can the task argument is still undefined

Comment: Is this what you've tried: `style: {color: $root.CssBind.bind(null, task)}`?

Comment: undefined in this way